What was the "lost" chapter from 'The Ring of Solomon'?
After re-reading the Bartimaeus sequence recently, I took a look at the series's official website, which has a couple of offcuts from The Amulet of Samarkand. The website is quite antiquated - no HTTPS, several broken links, etc. but still seems to have news articles published recently. The page on The Ring of Solomon has a broken link with the text "View the lost chapter of The Ring of Solomon". It seems to be referring to this post in the archives:

'Lost' Bart chapter is let out into the world as The Ring of Solomon publishes in paperback!
5 August 2011
Today sees UK publication of the paperback edition of The Ring of
Solomon, the fourth book in the Bartimaeus sequence. To celebrate this
publication Jonathan has exclusively released an extract from an early
draft of the book that has never been seen before. Click on the cover,
right, to read the lost chapter. Also check out Jonathan's Facebook
fan page where he hung out (virtually) yesterday answering questions
from his fans.

The "cover on the right" is, or was, a Flash application: http://static.issuu.com/webembed/viewers/style1/v1/IssuuViewer.swf, and Flash is dead.
Is the text of that lost chapter still available, maybe archived somewhere as text?

The flash application that's not working is simply an embedding of the issuu flipbook of the chapter, which you can theoretically find here: https://issuu.com/brilliant_books/docs/ring_of_solomon_lost_chapter_final
But as you can see, it's currently listed as publication access limited.
